# WFS layers disappear when zooming out, does not appear back when zooming in

Tags: qgis, wfs, zoom, display

I work with a wfs layer. Because they are lots of features in this layer and wfs visualization can not handle them all, I unchecked the "cache" box.

It works all fine except that some entities disappear when zooming out (scale-dependent rendering), and do not come back when zooming in again. Seems like the wfs protocol is looking for new entities only at zoom out, and that the ones that disappear due to rendering issues are not coming back.

Does anyone as an idea on whether this analysis is correct, and how to overcome the problem ?

Comment: Your analysis is correct as far as I know. I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this similar?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340223/leaflet-making-features-gone-when-zoom-out